# Azure App Service container keeps restarting - "Container failed availability check."

Tags: .net, azure, docker, containers

Sorry, I can't provide you a reproducible example but I hope you can help me to figure out what's going wrong in my environment.

I run a **windows container** based .NET 4.7 application inside a PC3 App Service Plan (16GB RAM). The application exposes a REST API and is also a JobHost that gets triggered on certain BlobStorage Events.

The whole business logic works fine - it runs without any issues locally and it does also run a limit time (1 - 5 min) on Azure. However, somehow the container gets restarted every x minutes and I am not able to figure out why.

This is what I see in the **container logs**:

```
02/10/2019 12:23:46.142 INFO - Site: myapp - Container failed availability check. It has failed 122895 check(s). Container will be declared unavailable if it exceeds 3 consecutive failed checks.
02/10/2019 12:23:46.142 ERROR - Site: myapp - Container is unavailable.
02/10/2019 12:23:47.129 INFO - Site: myapp - Container failed availability check. It has failed 5 check(s). Container will be declared unavailable if it exceeds 3 consecutive failed checks.
02/10/2019 12:23:47.129 ERROR - Site: myapp - Container is unavailable.
....
02/10/2019 12:23:56.862 INFO - Site: myapp - Attempting to stop container: 310a7f2278cdb56...
02/10/2019 12:23:56.895 INFO - Site: myapp - Purging pending logs after stopping container
02/10/2019 12:23:56.895 INFO - Site: myapp - Container stopped successfully. Container Id: 310a7f2278cdb56....
```

I have no idea why the availability check fails. Can someone explain to me how the check works and how I can get further information on why it fails?

Comment: is maybe something configured here?! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability#create-a-url-ping-test

Comment: Do you mean the windows container works fine locally?

Comment: yes! @CharlesXu

Comment: Which base image do you use?

Comment: @CharlesXu I use the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.7.2-windowsservercore-ltsc2019` base image. Can you give me any further information how the availability check works?

Comment: I also realized, that my container only gets 1,6 GB RAM - but my App Service Plan has 16 GB and I don't run any other container / web app inside it. Any idea?

Comment: I also do not meet the same issue. I just doubt if the base is not supported in Web App for container.

Comment: @CharlesXu I think the issue could be either the RAM (why I only get 1,6GB?) or maybe that my container is not responsible for the availability check because it is blocked by a running job. It would probably help me to get further information about how the check works.

Comment: If you think the issue is the RAM, then you just need to try to expand the RAM in the plan while the plan is only owned by yourself. If the application is a little one, I think the 1.6GB is enough.

Comment: @CharlesXu My plan has 16 GB and it only runs 1 container....

Comment: You cannot delete and recreate it? This is the simplest way.

Comment: The container gets recreated like 10 times / hour itself.....

Comment: I mean recreate it with more than 1.6 GB to check if it really caused the issue by less RAM.

Comment: How can I recreate it with more than 1.6GB RAM? I don't specify a limit anywhere. I can only specify the Image source (Azure Container Registry) and the Image / Tag that I wan't to run....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The App Service platform periodically checks for your container's availability by trying to reach the container on it's http endpoint.  If the container doesn't respond, or takes more than 5 seconds to respond, we assume the availability check failed.  If there are three consecutive failures we assume the container is unhealthy, stop it and start again.

If your application is memory/resource intensive it is likely that the container might not be able to respond within these parameters.

We introduced some application settings which you can set on your app which will enable you to control the actions when availability checks fail:

CONTAINER_AVAILABILITY_CHECK_MODE=Repair

The platform checks for availability and stops and restart the container after 3 consecutive availability checks (default)

CONTAINER_AVAILABILITY_CHECK_MODE=ReportOnly

The platform checks for availability and reports (in the logs) the container after 3 consecutive availability checks (default). The platform doesn’t stop/restart the container

CONTAINER_AVAILABILITY_CHECK_MODE=Off

The platform doesn’t check for availability

We also have a [Windows Containers on App Service wiki](https://aka.ms/appservicewindowscontainerwiki) for items which you may find useful which haven't been incorporated into our documentation so far.

Comment: So if multiple containers are being deployed in MultiContainer approach, then failing of one container can cause of restart for all the containers?